# proofing shortest paths in Graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given that the distance between two vertices u and v is the shortest path, proof that any two points that lie between u and v the distance (between those 2 points) have the shortest path. I have tried to proof this for a while but have not had any luck. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Proof by contradiction. Suppose that there exists a shorter path...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that this is what you mean:

> Let $u$ and $v$ be vertices in a graph. Suppose that there exists a shortest path from $u$ to $v$. Let $x$ and $y$ be two vertices that lie on the path from $u$ to $v$. Prove that the shortest path from $x$ to $y$ coincides with the shortest path from $u$ to $v$.

To prove this, let $E$ be the path from $u$ to $v$, and let $L$ be the length of that portion of $E$ between $x$ and $y$. Suppose that there is another path from $x$ to $y$ with length less than $L$. Then can you use that to construct a path from $u$ to $v$ that is shorter than $E$?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not that clear. The proof should be that if u=v0,v1,....vk=v is the shortest path from u to v, then for all i < j the path vi+1,vi+2,....vj is the shortest path from vi to vj. Does this clarify?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I figured you meant. But make sure your questions are very clear. You'll be more likely to get a quick, accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm fairly new to this so I'll keep that in mind for my next question.