# example of a graph that is not connected that has a cycle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

the graph includes 10 vertices and 9 edges.
any idea how a graph like this looks like. I have  been trying to draw one out with no luck, and any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Place nine of the vertices in a circle, and connect each vertex with the two next to it (a nonagon). This takes up nine vertices and all nine edges. Then put the last vertex somewhere with no edges connecting to it.

Comment: Thanks!  do you have an idea on how to tackles this qustion ?[(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719523/proofing-shortest-paths-in-graphs?noredirect=1#comment3510246_1719523)]